# How to Link Cells in Column to Cell in Rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, hyperlink

I have an Excel database. I want to link Column cells to Row Cells. One by one doing this will take so much time. I want to use some formula. Please help. Apart from that I also want to link cells to each other. Means when i click on Cell in Column. It should take me to linked Row Cell. and when i click on same row cell, it should bring me back to same cell in column.

Answer (score 1):

If we have a column of data, say **A1** through **A21** and we want to link a row to it, pick a cell and enter:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$11,COLUMNS($A:A),0)
```

and copy across:

[image]

Once this is done, hyperlinks can be assigned either manually or through a VBA macro.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the easiest way is this:

1. Count the number of rows and columns in the *Source* range.
2. Select a the *Destination* range of cells with the opposite number of rows and columns (e.g. if the original range had 3 columns and 2 rows, the target range would have 2 columns and 3 rows).
3. With the *Destination* range cells selected, type "*=TRANSPOSE(*" (use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to autocomplete).
4. Select the source rows
5. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

The animation below demonstrates the process in Excel 2010 with a 1 row x 3 column scenario.

[image]